# Snap feature for Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, window-manager, utilities, 3rd-party

Coming from Windows I have gotten extremely used to the Windows Snap feature, which resizes a window when it's dragged to the screen edges.

However, it's not built into OS X. Are there any 3rd party utilities that add this functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For window arranging:

- [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/)  $13
- [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/)  $14
- [Breeze](http://www.autumnapps.com/breeze/)  $8
- [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt)  Free
- [Mercury Mover](http://www.heliumfoot.com/mercurymover/details)  $20
- [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/)  $14
- [Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/)  $7
- [Moom](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moom/id419330170?mt=12)  $10

Comment: Damn that's a good list.

Comment: I'd personally vouch for free  [ShiftIt 1.5 by fukkovnik](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt).

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x similar question, I use Moom which i know specifically does have the snap feature described.

Comment: [Better Touch Tool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) also does it and is free.

Comment: Coming from Windows/Linux... these prices are _shocking_. :S

Comment: BetterTouchTool is not free anymore.

Comment: You may add Magnet, which works quite well for me https://apps.apple.com/de/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12

Answer (score 9):

[Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com) was mentioned in a question that was marked as duplicate of this one, but has not yet appeared here. It is also open source:

- [Spectacle at Github](https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle)

Also, OS X El Capitan (OS X 10.11) will have a side-to-side snap feature when it is released later in 2015 using Mission Control.

Comment: Spectacle is rather new, it's open source, the menu is simple, and it works well.

Answer (score 5):

This functionality is now built into Mac OS. Hold down the green resize button, and you then get an overlay on both sides of the screen that show which side you will be snapping to.

Comment: Indeed! Here's a more detailed overview, with screenshots: http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/use-os-x-el-capitans-new-split-screen-mode

Comment: The built in feature works only in fullscreen mode with exactly two windows. It's also way less efficient than just dragging the window to a side or a corner

Comment: @FelixGeenen Yes. The built in feature is limited, but it is available.

Answer (score 4):

You may also be looking for [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) (13$). That emulates the Windows Snap features better, I think.

Comment: Agreed. My only reason for preferring HyperDock is cost and features, especially if you come from Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

Your looking for [HyperDock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.de/)  ($9.95)

> HyperDock brings advanced window management features to Mac OS:
>    - Move & resize windows just by holding down keys and moving your mouse.
>    - Automatically resize windows when dragging to screen edges (Window Snapping).

Comment: Love HyperDock!  It also adds an Aero Peek affect (window preview by hovering over the dock icon.)

Answer (score 3):

I use [bettertouchtool](http://blog.boastr.net/) which includes this feature for free

this also alows you to create custom gestures for your trackpad / magic mouse / magic trackpad

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered another utility (released via the Mac App Store just today!) that seems to provide the exact functionality as Windows Snap. It's called [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) ($5), and it adds an iOS-style popover to the green Maximize button in Mac windows. The popover has buttons that let you do the following:

- Restore original position
- Zoom to full screen
- Move to left, zoom to half width
- Move to right, zoom to half width
- Move to top, zoom to half height
- Move to bottom, zoom to half height

You can use the mouse or keyboard to invoke any of this window moving and zooming, and you get additional functionality if you use the keyboard. I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like just the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/)

> Cinch gives you simple, mouse-driven window management by defining the left, right, and top edges of your screen as 'hot zones'. Drag a window until the mouse cursor enters one of these zones then drop the window to have it cinch into place.

Comment: Any particular reason you deleted my inclusion of additional information?

Comment: @Diago - I just rolled it back to your version, as it provides more information.

Answer (score 1):

[Cinch](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/) ($7) works a lot like Aero Snap.

Most of the time it's more convenient to use keyboard shortcuts though. For that I'd recommend [ShiftIt](http://code.google.com/p/shiftit/). It's free, extremely simple and also has an action for Windows-style maximize.

For those possibly looking for snapping windows to screen elements: [Zooom/2](http://coderage-software.com/zooom/index_green/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Magnet, [available on the Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/app/magnet/id441258766) for **$7.99** by CrowdCafé is pretty good

Answer (score 0):

Since **Spectacle** from the top answer is no longer actively maintained, i would recommend [Rectangle](https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle) as the closest replacement for the Snap feature from Windows.

By default you could snap windows to the sides, top/button or in the edges. There are also customizable shortcuts for doing so.

And the best part: It is free :)