# Native OS X Windows Snap Features 2018

Tags: window-manager

As an Ubuntu and MS-Windows user, I regularly used the hotkey to snap a window to half the screen.  This feature was built-in to the operating system.   [There are 7 year old threads which lists third party apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9426/snap-feature-for-mac), which means enough time has elapsed to build the capability into the OS.

Question: What is the proper term that one would use to search?  Is the capability baked into 2018 versions (10.11.6) of OSX?

Comment: Some minimal window snapping feature is built in, but it doesn't offer the same kind of functionality as Windows or BetterSnapTool / Magnet: http://osxdaily.com/2016/12/06/use-window-snapping-mac/

Answer (score 6):

It’s not baked in. [Magnet](http://magnet.crowdcafe.com/) seems to be the most popular app, and it’s what I use.

Answer (score -2):

As Microsoft has patented windows snapping feature in order to prevent lawsuit Apple hasn't natively added this feature into MacOS

[image: I learnt this from linus tech tips]

My suggestions would be if you are ok with third party apps

1.Magnet 
2.Better snap tool
3.Spectacles

If you want to use something simple natively on Mac without third party then use mission control trackpad gestures or set shortcuts as per your needs to use Mac like a pro multitasker with multiple desktops here is my example

[image: System prefrences - Keyboard - Shortcuts]

**And when using mission control you can add apps to split screen just by swiping them to desired desktop**

Comment: You **cannot** patent a feature, only the method by which it’s done, so no, Apple has not refrained from including that feature as a mitigation against litigation.   If that were the case, the three apps you referenced would be long gone by now. Why Apple chooses to do or not do something is for them.

Comment: Interesting speculation there - maybe put that at the end after you answer if you get some down votes or people focus on the _why_ you mention instead of the _what_ that answers the question

Comment: Check the edit above for patent @Allan even I didn't know until I checked out Linus tech tips video but you got a point too its up to apple if they choose to do something similar in function

Comment: If you notice, the very first words of the patent “**A method for displaying*...”