# Tile *Previous* Window Side-by-Side with Current

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, window-manager

I'm well aware of Moom, BetterTouchTool, BetterSnapTool, Divvy, and Spectacle, and have thoroughly read [this question's answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50330/how-to-arrange-two-windows-easily-to-left-and-right-side).

I don't think any of the above can:

with **one** keyboard stroke, tile the current window and the *previously-focused window* side-by-side.

Moom allows application-specific configurations; all the others allow manipulating only the *current-focused* window.

This is something I find that I'm doing over and over again, for example: switching from a PDF to my browser to type some info from the PDF into my browser; I'd like to quickly show them side-by-side so that it's easy to copy over, say, an address.

Comment: so you always want this to work with browser and Preview say.

Comment: or do applications vary?

Comment: @jmh applications vary; that was just an example. Moom can probably do Preview and browser specifically, but sometimes I also want Evernote and Preview, Evernote and Browser, etc. etc. and it'd be unbelievably tedious to encode every pairwise combo I'd need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273242/is-there-anything-like-winsplit-revolution-for-mac-os-x/537115#537115

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9426/snap-feature-for-mac

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via AppleScript.

I might be able to fudge some kind of script for you in a day or so, but take a look at:

http://tom.scogland.com/blog/2013/06/08/mac-raise-window-by-title/
(mostly for how to make the script non-specific to an an application) and  https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/04.html
(for relative window indexes).

I don't unfortunately know the scripting terminology for placing windows side-by-side, so either someone else can take a crack at it, or I will in a couple days.

Comment: Looks like there are some good leads here, cheers. The second link seems to be able to manipulate the second-_layer_ window, although I'm not clear if it can do 'previously-focused window' (regardless of what layer it happens to be on) _per se_. Then again, come to think of it, those things are equivalent in most important cases perhaps.