# Can I snap windows to fill 1/4 of the screen like in Windows?

Tags: macos, mojave, desktop, window-manager, split-view

I know you can 'pin' two windows left/right on Mac through the full-screen option but is there no simple shortcut like on Windows, to resize/move just the current window top/left and bottom/right? In Windows you can easily get up to 4 windows neatly arranged and I am struggling to believe Windows is ahead of Mac in terms of user interface... so how can I do this?

Comment: I’ve added the [window-manager](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-manager) tag as it has many of people’s favorite tools like moom and divvy - many others offer snap and automation. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9426/snap-feature-for-mac

Answer (score 1):

There’s an App that I use to gain the Windows “snap” like functionality in macOS - [Magnet](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12)

There are a number of configurable shortcuts that allow you to snap Windows in halves, thirds, quarters, etc.  It costs $2USD, but is well worth the price

[image]

Comment: I use BetterSnapTool, which is broadly similar.

Comment: Search here for moom or divvy = there are some awesome window manager options.

Comment: It is currently $10, which is a bit pricey for window resizing...