# (macOS) Two windows side by side: is there a way to allow stretching one window to minimum width?

Tags: macos, catalina, window-manager

***My daily case:*** I usually have .pdf viewer for articles + MS Word side by side and Web browser + markdown side by side.

My struggle is windows stretching - for example, when I read .pdf I would like to shring MS Words window to minimum, however, macOS allow me to like 35 % (my guess), some goes for the Web browser + markdown.

Is there a way to set the stretching percentage of each window?

This is an illustration of my question:

[image]

Comment: Haven't you consider https://www.spectacleapp.com. It's no longer under active development, but is still usable under macOS 10.15.6 Catalina

Comment: Can you illustrate this with a diagram? Pictures of what you want might let us suggest a better window manager or roll like [moom](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303909/5472), [divvy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228194/5472), many others (so many other great options)

Comment: @modlin No, I haven't, I will look into it. However, my intention is to always avoid 3rd party Apps for such purposes if possible.

Comment: It’s not macOS that’s stopping you.  Applications themselves can set how “small“ or “large” the window can be; in other words, it can limit its *dimensions* to a certain point. You may need to rethink your workflow.

Comment: I use a tool called [Magnet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387513/119271) to arrange my Windows similar to what you want to do.

Comment: Brilliant diagram! Thanks - when I’m back at a Mac I’ll see if I can help any.

Comment: @Allan That's what I was thinking. Honestly, I didn't expect there is much I can do - I tried to google advice, but couldn't find any, so I tried this forum. As for Magnet, I bought this App few months ago :) However, I couldn't enter full windows mode and the Apps didn't change its size together, which let's say is still "OK", but for this I don't even need to use Magnet - I can just open two windows side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

[You can do this with Applescript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303913/5472). Set the boundaries for the front window to be a certain width. Then after clicking on the window you want to shrink, run your Applescript. Name your script something like narrow_front_window.sc.  The script could look something like:

tell application "Finder" to set the bounds of the front Finder window to {36, 115, 511, 674}

Just run the script after bringing window to the front.  The widows do have a minimum size.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, this won't change the possibility of windows shrinkage boundaries "forever", am I correct?

Comment: @Josh E. RE: " this won't change the possibility of windows shrinkage boundaries "forever"" -- What do you mean by this? It is as unclear as your question!

Comment: jmh, Not all apps and windows have or use the `bounds` _property_, nor do all apps have the direct ability to manipulate its windows using **AppleScript** unless **System Events** is used to do it using `position` _property_ and or `size` _property_.  Therefore your `tell application "Finder" ...` example doesn't cover all scenarios. Even the linked answer that bmike edited into your answer is not complete and is only specific to the question asked that I wrote that answer for.  RE: "Name your script something like narrow_front_window.sc." -- **AppleScript** scripts have a `.scpt` extension.

Comment: Ah yes,  i see the problems now looking back at the question.  i should have read it a few more times.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @user3439894 From the reply I understood that I should repeat this step every time - so that the setting won't stay. I am not that good with scripts or any macOS management via terminal. I just wanted to allow re-sizing either left or right window, while I'm having two windows opened side by side, to "absolute minimum / maximum" it stops at certain width extension.